# Vector as a choice in shiny::selectInput()

Tags: r, shiny

Here is a working template:

```
require(data.table)
require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)

x <- data.table(v1 = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = T), 
                v2 = sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace = T),
                v3 = runif(100, 0, 1))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("in1", "Choice v1", selected = "All", choices = c("All" = list(letters[1:5]))),
    selectInput("in2", "Choice v2", selected = "a", choices = letters[1:2])
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("out1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$out1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(x[v1 %in% input$in1 & v2 %in% input$in2], aes(x = v3)) +
      geom_density(fill = "dodgerblue4", alpha = .7) +
      theme_light()
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Issue here is that I'd like to allow for selection of subset of values within variable. Line `selectInput("in1", "Choice v1", selected = "All", choices = c("All" = list(letters[1:5])))` was intended to pass `letters[1:5]` to `input$in1` effectively selecting all values and performing no subsetting of data on `v1`.

Same applies to any other subset of values e.g. choice `"a_b_c" = c("a", "b", "c")`, or `"All" = x[,unique(v1)]` and so on. What shiny does, is break up list to all values included in it, basically achieving opposite of desired result.
I know there is `selectizeInput()` to select multiple values. However, this is not viable if I want `selected = "All"` for all variables as initial state.

Answer (score 4):

Would something like this work?

```
#rm(list=ls())
require(data.table)
require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)

x <- data.table(v1 = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = T), 
                v2 = sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace = T),
                v3 = runif(100, 0, 1))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("in1", "Choice v1", selected = "All", choices = c("All",letters[1:5])),
    selectInput("in2", "Choice v2", selected = "a", choices = letters[1:2])
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("out1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$out1 <- renderPlot({
    value <- input$in1
    if(value == "All"){
      value <- letters[1:5]
    }
    ggplot(x[v1 %in% value & v2 %in% input$in2], aes(x = v3)) +
      geom_density(fill = "dodgerblue4", alpha = .7) +
      theme_light()
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it would. That was possible workaround that I should have mentioned in post. It eventually bloats with quite a lot of temporary variables  if you have, say, 10 variables all set to "All" as initial state. And have several levels of aggregations within each variable selection... otherwise it is perfectly valid option. I was just hoping for direct solution within shiny framework.

Comment: Cool, but how can I change this code to ´if(value == "All"){ command 1 } if(value == "a"){ command 2 }´  etc

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have vector values as a possible choice in a Shiny input, I suggest to  apply jsonlite::toJSON to the vector before passing it to the selectInput (later when you access the value, you use jsonlite::fromJSON.) Make sure you have the package jsonlite installed:

```
require(data.table)
require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)

x <- data.table(v1 = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = T), 
                v2 = sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace = T),
                v3 = runif(100, 0, 1))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("in1", "Choice v1", selected = "All", choices = c("All" = jsonlite::toJSON(letters[1:5]))),
    selectInput("in2", "Choice v2", selected = "a", choices = letters[1:2])
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("out1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$out1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(x[v1 %in% jsonlite::fromJSON(input$in1) & v2 %in% input$in2], aes(x = v3)) +
      geom_density(fill = "dodgerblue4", alpha = .7) +
      theme_light()
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Answer (score 0):

`shiny` supports selection of multiple values in `selectInput`. You need to set `multiple = TRUE` and `selectize = FALSE`.  I think this will provide you the functionality you desire.

You then make the `choices` and `selected` variables the same to preselect all of the variables.  If you need to use an "all" feature, you'll need to add an action button to run `updateSelectInput`.  Combining those two features could be done by writing a module.

```
require(data.table)
require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)

x <- data.table(v1 = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = T), 
                v2 = sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace = T),
                v3 = runif(100, 0, 1))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("in1", "Choice v1", 
                selected = letters[1:5], 
                choices = letters[1:5],
                multiple = TRUE,
                selectize = FALSE),
    selectInput("in2", "Choice v2", 
                selected = letters[1:2], 
                choices = letters[1:2],
                multiple = TRUE,
                selectize = FALSE)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("out1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$out1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(x[v1 %in% input$in1 & v2 %in% input$in2], aes(x = v3)) +
      geom_density(fill = "dodgerblue4", alpha = .7) +
      theme_light()
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Comment: This not quite the direction I'd like to go. It's very similar to selectize option in own sense, it does not scale well. I mean, it's not a good solution for this part of question: `"a_b_c" = c("a", "b", "c")`. Imagine if initially you have basic city aggregation. Then I'd like a selection of country and another level of aggregation - by continent. And on top of it all - total, or global.

Comment: I'm considering to make a separate data table just for mapping and refer to selection through it... that currently seems like the only viable solution.

Comment: In that case, I think you're probably better off with Pork Chop's answer.  I question the value of adding an `"a_b_c"` option to the select box.  If you're only permitting the user to select one value at a time, you may need to provide every permutation of the options, which will bloat the user interface--something that has a higher cost than bloating the server-side code (at least in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

While reading other answers and wondering about possible clean and compact workaround, here's what I came up with. It was crucial to have clean approach to adding new variables.

```
require(data.table)
require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)

x <- data.table(v1 = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = T), 
                v2 = sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace = T),
                v3 = runif(100, 0, 1))

map.dt <- function(x, variables){
  map.out <- data.table(name = character(), variable = character(), value = character())
  for(i in variables){
    map.out <- rbind(map.out,
                     data.table(name = x[,sort(as.character(na.omit(unique(get(i)))))],
                                variable = i,
                                value = x[,sort(as.character(na.omit(unique(get(i)))))]),
                     data.table(name = "All",
                                variable = i,
                                value = x[,sort(as.character(na.omit(unique(get(i)))))]))
  }
  return(map.out)
}

y <- map.dt(x, c("v1", "v2"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("in1", "Choice v1", selected = "All", choices = c("All", letters[1:5])),
    selectInput("in2", "Choice v2", selected = "All", choices = c("All", letters[1:2]))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("out1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$out1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(x[v1 %in%  y[variable == "v1" & name == input$in1, value] & 
               v2 %in% y[variable == "v2" & name == input$in2, value]], 
             aes(x = v3)) +
      geom_density(fill = "dodgerblue4", alpha = .7) +
      theme_light()
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Basically, it's adding an intermediate mapping table which is generated via function.